# What is OpenMage Magento-lts?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, magento-connect, marketplace, openmage

What is OpenMage magento-lts? and how it works? What are the main difference between magento 1.9 and OpenMage Magento-lts? What type of extensions does it use. Please explain in detail. I don't know anything about it.

Comment: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/blob/1.9.4.x/README.md

Comment: https://www.openmage.org/magento-lts/about.html

Comment: Hi Amit Bera will you tell me how to install and all. Is it come with sample data?

Answer (score 2):

OpenMage is a community-driven Magento1-Fork. A drop-in replacement for M1 ... see https://www.openmage.org/magento-lts/about.html

It includes hundreds of bugfixes, performances and security updates beyond latest 1.9.4.5 release.

> What are the main difference between magento 1.9 and OpenMage Magento-lts?

Most important ... it is activly maintained. ;)

Support for php7.0-7.4, mysql-8, composer (also composer2) ...

> What type of extensions does it use.

No one. There are no preinstalled extensions. ([N98-LayoutHelper](https://github.com/netz98/N98_LayoutHelper) is (almost) completely integrated, nothing else.) Only core fixes/improvements.

> Hi Amit Bera will you tell me how to install and all. Is it come with sample data?

It is installable with composer, ddev or custom [docker setup](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/tree/1.9.4.x/dev/openmage). There is no sample data, but i#m recently working on it.